# Can not delete documents in local database CouchBase lite

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

I am using `CouchBase Lite 1.3` with `Android` over `CouchDB 1.6` .

If I delete a document on CouchDB the document is not deleted on my device local replication DB.

This is my code:

```
  private Database master;
    private Manager manager;
    public Replication pullmaster;

    manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(c), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    master = manager.getDatabase("master");
    pullmaster = master.createPullReplication(url);

     master.addChangeListener(new Database.ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(Database.ChangeEvent event) {
                        if (event.isExternal()) {
                            for (DocumentChange dc : event.getChanges()) {

                                if (dc.isDeletion()) {
                                    Document doc = event.getSource().getDocument(dc.getDocumentId());
                                    try {
                                        doc.purge();
                                    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

  startReplicators();
```

And here I start the replication

```
public void startReplicators() {
        if (pullmaster != null) {
            pullmaster.start();
        }
        if (pullwork != null) {
            pullwork.start();
        }
        if (pushwork != null) {
            pushwork.start();
        }
    }
```

It does not work, I mean It does not delete the document I am deleting in `CouchDb`, no errors are getting.

I have put a break point on this line

> master.addChangeListener(new Database.ChangeListener() {....}

If I create a document in CouchDB  `addChangeListener()` is called but if I deleted the document the method is not called.

Any clue about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you start a replication?

Comment: Thanks @borrrden Yes I did

Comment: @borrrden I have added the replication class to my question

Comment: @borrrden I have also the object  private Database workData;   with the same implemention that private Database master;    with  workData works . Can I have two Database.ChangeListener() for tow databases ??

Comment: Not related to your question, but note that CouchDB 1.6 has a very serious security flaw, and should be upgraded to CouchDB 1.7 or 2.1 immediately.

Comment: Your code shows you creating a replication, but not starting it.  Just to confirm, you started it right?  Also note that Couchbase Lite 1.3 has reached end of life so beyond some basic troubleshooting there won't be any support.

Comment: Also yes, you can have two change listeners for two databases there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: added starting replicators to my question. Shall I start the replication before or after the listener? 
I think that couchbase lite 2.0 does not support CouchDB is no it?

Comment: Couchbase Lite 2.0 does not support CouchDB, but you can use the latest 1.x (just know that eventually that will be out of support as well).  Repilcator can be started at any time, it does not matter.

Comment: Are you using a filtered replication? If so, the deleted documents may not pass the filter and thus you never get the notification.

Comment: On a separate note, I've had problems with Couchbase Lite filtering replication to CouchDB and we had to move away from CBL because of it. See https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-lite-to-couchdb-filtered-replication-in-android/10803 about possible incompatibility

Comment: @HypnicJerk thanks, Yes I use filtering replication. 
Have you  tried this solution in order to use filtering replication with couchDB? 
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/942

Comment: We did. Ultimately the main problem is your deleted document no longer passes the filter, so instead of actually deleting the document, why not add a field called delete and set it to true, then in your app, dont show any deleted documents but leave the filter the same. This will mimic your functionality, even if it doesnt actually remove the documents.

Answer (score 1):

In Couchbase Lite version 2.7.0, You can delete documents from database based on `id` as following:

```
try {
        for (Result result : docList) {
            String id = result.getString(0);
            Document doc = database.getDocument(id);
            database.delete(doc);
        }
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To get the document id you have to query something like this:

```
Query query = QueryBuilder
    .select(SelectResult.expression(Meta.id), SelectResult.all())
    .from(DataSource.database(database))

ResultSet rs = query.execute();
    for (Result result : rs) {
        Dictionary data = result.getDictionary("db_name");
        Log.e("CouchbaseLite ", "document: " + data);
        Log.e("CouchbaseLite ", "id: " + result.getString(0));
    }
```